# View component in designer from code view

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

In visual studios community edition 2015, I have components that are initialized in the xxx.designer.cs, and show in the designer view. I also alter them in the class code, xxx.cs. For instance when reading a config file I will set items to checked.

My question is, from the code view, is there a way I can have it show me the component in the designer view?

IE: I have code saying to check a checkbox and I want to right click and say, show my component in designer.

EDIT: using the dropdown list of element is easier than searching the designer for it but I was hoping there was a shortcut. Any ideas?

EDIT2: Shift+F7 will take me to the designer but doesn't highlight the component I want to find, and since I'm working with someone elses's bad code with hundreds of components in one form it's still very difficult to find.

Answer (score 2):

You want to jump from an element's code to where it is in designer? I think you can click within the code's scope and hit f7. Alternatively look at what the element's name is and view drop down of page elements in a designer window.

Comment: Yes that is what I want. F7 didn't work. The element name in drop down is helpful though not quite as good as a shortcut would be.

Comment: Thanks - I was wondering what was this "drop down of page elements in a designer window", and I think in VS2019 community, it is right below the title bar of the "Properties" tab (typically on the right) when looking at a Design view of a form.